# ConTeXt: Letterspacing in style alternative

Tags: context, kerning, letterspacing

I want to create a new style alternative, which would allow me to change the text and font (to uppercase bold in this example) while also increasing the letterspacing. However, trying to do this leads to a crash:

```
\setuppapersize[S3]

\definecharacterkerning [mykerning] [factor=0.16]
\definealternativestyle [mystyle]
  [
    \WORDS\bfx\setcharacterkerning[mykerning]
  ]


\starttext
  {\WORDS\bfx\setcharacterkerning[mykerning] It works here.}
  
  {\mystyle It crashes here.}
\stoptext
```

```
tex error       > tex error on line 13 in file /home/…/test.tex: ! Argument of \setcharacterkerning has an extra }
```

Why does this crash occur? (`\WORDS` works, why not `\setcharacterkerning`?) Is there a way to fix it? I want to be able to use it as an argument for `style=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Sorry for the long answer. The bracket issue was discussed elsewhere and I think it's explained in a manual, but I don't remember which, so I'll include a brief note here.</sub>

Your problem is: ConTeXt is closing a pair of brackets `[]` at the first occurrence of the closing bracket. Thus, something like

```
\setupsomething[key=\value[]]
```

will read `[key=\value[]` and crash. For such situations ConTeXt provides `\setups` to include all your complicated macros:

```
\startsetups mystyle 
\WORDS\bfx\setcharacterkerning[mykerning]
\stopsetups
```

Both `\setups[mystyle]` and `\setup{mystyle}` work, so we'll choose the latter in order to avoid the bracket issue above.

```
\setuppapersize[S3]
\definecharacterkerning [mykerning] [factor=0.16]
\startsetups mystyle
\WORDS\bfx\setcharacterkerning[mykerning]
\stopsetups
\definealternativestyle[mystyle][\setups{mystyle}]
\setuphead[title][style=\mystyle]
%Test example
\starttext
\starttitle[title=Hello]
\input jojomayer
\stoptitle
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: A simpler solution is to wrap the content of the argument in curly braces, e.g. `\definealternativestyle[mystyle][{\setcharactercasing[WORD]...}].`

Comment: @WolfgangSchuster I've tried that, but character spacing doesn't have any effect in latest LMTX... I'll see again

Comment: I think I found the problem – encapsulating it with braces does not work with how I format the argument (with new lines and indentation). Why does it affect it here, but not elsewhere?

Comment: @JurajFiala Your example doesn't include new lines or indentation. Maybe you should include it in your MWE, because I'm testing here and it works across paragraphs.

Comment: It does, see `\definealternativestyle`. If I join lines 4–7 and encapsulate it with braces, it works.

Comment: @JurajFiala Oh, nice, I understood the opposite.